# CreateProcess from within Screen Saver

Tags: windows, winapi, createprocess, screensaver, windows-screensaver

I need to start "explorer.exe" from within my screensaver, but whatever I tried it wont stay opened when my screen saver closes.

```
CreateProcess(nil, 'explorer.exe /select,"' + fileName + '"', nil, nil, false, 0, nil, '', StartupInfo, ProcessInfo)
```

I tried multitude of combination of flags and parameters, no luck :)
Explorer starts briefly and closes with my screensaver app...

There is a solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890243/spawning-child-processes-in-a-screensaver) but it requires windows service and that is too much for a simple screen saver...

Anyone got a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your screen saver app running when a user logged on or not?

Comment: Logged on, no lock activated

Comment: Child process will not exits when parent exits. Have you tried start other application instead of `explorer.exe` to see if it reproduces the same issue?

Comment: Yup, same behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself,
I create a Windows Task with current logged in user to start in 2sec after ss closes. And it works great.

Here is the command for creating the task:

```
powershell -command "& {Register-ScheduledTask -Action $(New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "explorer.exe" -Argument '/select,"d:/test/txt" ') -Trigger $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(2)) -TaskName "MyTask" -TaskPath "MyTasks" -Principal $(New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $(Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -expand UserName))}"
```

and dont forget to delete the task before create the new one - or the create fails

```
powershell -command "& {Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask" -Confirm:$false}"
```